# Подскажите, как протестировать методы, которые ничего не возвращают. Java

Tags: java, консоль, junit

Есть методы:

```
    static void solve(int x,int y,int k)
/*k - номер шага, x,y - координаты*/
{
    int i;

    if (x == xk & y == yk) {
        print(x,y,k);
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < Dx.length; i++)
            {
                if (a[x+Dx[i]][y+Dy[i]] != 0) {
                    if (x+Dx[i] >= 0 & y+Dy[i] >= 0) {
                        a[x][y] = 0; // чистим за собой препятствия, чтобы при возвращени на -1 мы потом снова не прибавили 1 в той же клетке !!!!
                        solve (x+Dx[i],y+Dy[i],k+1);
                    }       
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

    static void file() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String [] splitted;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("settings.txt"));

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        splitted = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        xn = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
        yn = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
        xk = Integer.parseInt(splitted[2]);
        yk = Integer.parseInt(splitted[3]);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                splitted = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
                for (int z = 0; z < splitted.length; z++)
                {
                    a[i][z] = Integer.parseInt(splitted[z]);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Массив в файле должен состоять из 5 строк по 5 значений в каждой.");
        }
    }
    sc.close(); 
}

    static void console()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        System.out.println("Введите лабиринт из 5 строк по 5 значений в каждой через пробел.");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String[] line = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            for (int z = 0; z < line.length; z++) 
            {
                a[i][z] = Integer.parseInt(line[z]);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("Лабиринт должен состоять из 5 строк и 5 значений, каждое значение через пробел.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Введите начальные координаты x: ");
    xn = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите начальные координаты y: ");
    yn = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите конечные координаты x: ");
    xk = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Введите конечные координаты y: ");
    yk = in.nextInt();

    in.close();
}
```

Как стандартными средствами можно их протестировать ? JUnit3.

Comment: Никак. Переписать чтобы возвращали.

Comment: В тестах можно также проверять, не выбрасывает ли код исключений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уж очень надо, можно проверить вывод в консоль, переназначив System.out на нужный поток вывода. Метод System.setOut(). Потом сравнивать что напечаталось и что ожидалось. Также, я так понял, ваши методы меняют переменные вне методов (xk, yk во втором методе), их тоже можно сравнить с ожидаемыми.

Answer (score 0):

Универсальный метод - расставить по коду выводы в консоль (либо задействовать логгер):

```
// НАЧАЛО вывод в консоль
System.out.println("Variable name: " + variable);
// КОНЕЦ вывод в консоль
```

Comment: Спросили не как отлаживать, а как тестировать.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать ASSERT для отладки ожидаемых результатов и промежуточных состояний (мы знаем что ожидаем и проверяем это) внутри методов и функций.... рекомендую к использованию.